# How To Vertically Divide A Web Page Without Using A Table?

Tags: html, tabular

I read somewhere (on Stack Overflow as a matter of fact!) that it's a bad idea to use tables to layout pages in html.

I have an HTML page that needs to be "divided" down the middle with some content going on the left and some content going on the right. At fist I would have thought to use nested tables with each of their widths being 50%. Can I do the same thing using *div*? Or some other html construct?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not, could you provide a demo or clarify your question?

Answer (score 10):

```
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
Left  <!-- Set Div As your requirement -->
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
Right  <!-- Set Div As your requirement -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Why is the right hand div not `float: right`?

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve (very basically) what you want.

```
body,html{height:100%}
div.mainLayout{float:left;width:50%}
div.clearFlt{clear:both}

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainLayout">LeftContent
        <div class="clearFlt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainLayout">LeftContent
        <div class="clearFlt"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One common way for a base layout is to wrap your areas into div containers. Those containers are positioned and sized using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll inspect the stackoverflow page (if using firefox, right-click on any element on the sidebar on the right, and select 'Inspect Element'), you'll see that the sidebar is a div element with a float attribute. No tables on the Inspector stack at the bottom of the page!

Comment: Hmmn ... I have it by default on Firefox v16.0.1 installed on Windows 7 that I am using now.